# How I retrive a lost password without changing or resetting it

Tags: iphone, password, facebook

I have Facebook on my iPhone and it works well because it has the password stored on it so I don't have to put it in every time I log in. Now I want to use Facebook on my new computer, but I forgot the password since I don't have to enter it each time I log in.

I really don't want to change the password because I have done that before and keep mixing them up.

Some one help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I'm not sure I understand what the question is here. Are you asking how to get the password off your iPhone? Please clarify by using the `edit` link above, and make sure your post is in the form of a question. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you take a look at 1Password so you don't have to forget it and change it ever again.

Comment: for next time: http://www.lastpass.com - which I prefer over http://www.1password.com - lol hey @Martin! marginalized minds do think alike, huh? :P

Answer (score 1):

Passwords on iOS are stored in a keychain, like in your MacBook. Here are sevaral possibilies, but honestly, I've never tried any.

- Retrieve the keychain from the iPhone backup - when you backing up your iPhone, the keychain is backed up too. This backup is encrypted, so you will need unlock it. Instructions on how to do this can be found elsewhere on the Internet.
- Both phones are already jailbroken - the easier way, if you know unix, ssh and command line, but probably this is not your case, and you would void the phone's warranty.

So, it is not an easy task to get access to your girlfriend's Facebook account. ;) /joke/

Comment: Jailbreaking an iPhone is not illegal and you don't lose your warranty as far as I know.

Comment: WOW, that's new for me. Thanx for the info - going to check.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini, you definitely lose your warranty, but you are correct that [it is not illegal](http://www.theverge.com/2015/10/27/9622066/jailbreak-unlocked-tablet-smart-tvs-dmca-exemption-library-of-congress), at least in the U.S.